# No puedo llamar al servicio en React

Tags: reactjs, graphql

estoy haciendo una aplicacion y a traves de un boton se dispara un evento onClick que llama a la funcion `loadMoreBooks` -> es en esta funcion en donde se llama al servicio el servicio es una querie que tengo en el archivo queries.js en donde esta el servicio en donde se pasan los argumentos pero de alguna forma recibo un error `loadMoreBooks no es una funcion`.

En el componente BookHome:

```
    class BookHome extends React.Component {
        
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            
            this.state = {
                books: []
            }
        
        }

        static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
            const { bookList: {bookList} } = props;
            if(bookList) {
                return {
                    books: bookList
                }
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        loadMoreBooks = async() => {
            const { loadMoreBooks } = this.props;
            const { books } = this.state;
            let lastBookId = books[books.length - 1].id;
            
            const variables = {
                bookId: lastBookId ? lastBookId : ''
            }

            try {
                const response = await loadMoreBooks({variables});
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        }

        render() {
            const { books } = this.state;
            return(
                <div className="books-home-container">
                    <div className="books-header-home"></div>
                    <SearchBar />
                    <Books books={books}/>
                    <LoadMoreButton loadMoreBooks={e => this.loadMoreBooks()}/>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default compose(
        graphql(queries.bookList, { name: 'bookList' }),
        graphql(queries.loadMoreBooks, { name: 'loadMoreBooks' })
    )(BookHome);
```

El archivo querie es el siguiente:
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

```
    const queries = {
        bookList: gql`
        query bookList {
            bookList {
                id
                coverImage
                title
                description
                author
                rating
            }
        }
        `,
        loadMoreBooks: gql`
        query loadMoreBooks($bookId: String!) {
            loadMoreBooks(bookId: $bookId) {
                id
                coverImage
                author
                title
            }
        }
        `,

    }

    export default queries;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RESUELTO`

Luego de debuggear el codigo en varias ocaciones, me di cuenta que estaba llamando cuando se renderizaba el componente al servicio, y este fallaba en el llamado porque espera que se le pase como argumento un Integer.

La `solucion` fue, agregar la variable `client` que se exporta desde index y hacer un llamado a la querie a partir de esta por lo que, estaria totalmente controlado el llamado por el evento onClick que llama a la funcion. Des esta forma:

```
      loadMoreBooks = async(e) => {
            const { books } = this.state;
            let lastBookId = books[books.length - 1].id;

            try {
                const resp = await client.query({
                    query: queries.getMoreBooks,
                    variables: { bookId: parseInt(lastBookId) },
                    fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
                });
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando define un componente usando una clase `ES6` , un patrón común es que un controlador de eventos sea un método en la clase, debes llamar a `bind` en el constructor para que no te de un error al usar un método:

```
 constructor(props) {
     super(props);   
     this.state = {
         books: []
     }
 this.loadMoreBooks = this.loadMoreBooks.bind(this)
 }
```

te aconsejo que uses los métodos como tal, y si es necesitas utilizar async/await en un método simplemente agrega el `async` antes de el nombre del método

```
async handle(){
//aqui la lógica del método
}
```

Comment: No uso bind en el constructor, en vez de ello utilizo arrow functions, lo que pasa es que cuando el componente va renderizando llama al servicio(siendo que deberia llamar al servicio cuando se dispara el evento onClick).

Comment: entonces solamente agregas la funcion al parametro, de esta forma `<LoadMoreButton loadMoreBooks={this.loadMoreBooks}/>` yo creo que con eso basta

Answer (score 0):

En el onClick intenta poner <Componente onClick={()=>this.loadMoreBooks.bind()}/>
o bien solo onClick={this.loadMoreBooks} y listo